# Reconexion automatica de bluetooth android studio

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Buenos dias.

Estoy desarrollando una app en android studio, en la cual me conecto por medio de bluetooth a la impresora.

El detalle es que si me salgo de la app se pierde la conexion bluetooth a la impresora, y lo que quiero es cuando inicie la app se vuelva a conectar a la impresora de forma automática, les dejo el código de como lo estoy tratando de hacer pero me truena la app

este archivo es que usa para que desde la conexión bluetooth a la impresora,esa si me funciona ya que es la uso en mi pantalla de configuración.

```
public class ConexionBluetooth extends Activity {


    private static final String TAG = "BluetoothConnectMenu";
    // Intent request codes
    // private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 2;

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private Vector<BluetoothDevice> remoteDevices;
    private BroadcastReceiver searchFinish;
    private BroadcastReceiver searchStart;
    private BroadcastReceiver discoveryResult;
    private Thread hThread;
    private Context context;
    private String MacAddres = "";
    private BroadcastReceiver reconectar;
    // UI
    private EditText btAddrBox;
    private Button connectButton;
    private Button searchButton;
    private ListView list;
    // BT
    private BluetoothPort bluetoothPort;

    // Activar Bluetooth en caso de no estar activado
    public void bluetoothSetup()
    {
        // Initialize
        clearBtDevData();
        bluetoothPort = BluetoothPort.getInstance();
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null)
        {
            // Device does not support Bluetooth
            return;
        }
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
        {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }
    }

    private static final String dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "//temp";
    private static final String fileName = dir + "//BTPrinter";
    private String lastConnAddr;
    private void loadSettingFile()
    {
        int rin = 0;
        char [] buf = new char[128];
        try
        {
            FileReader fReader = new FileReader(fileName);
            rin = fReader.read(buf);
            if(rin > 0)
            {
                lastConnAddr = new String(buf,0,rin);
                btAddrBox.setText(lastConnAddr);
            }
            fReader.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "No existe historia de conexiones.");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    private void saveSettingFile()
    {
        try
        {
            File tempDir = new File(dir);
            if(!tempDir.exists())
            {
                tempDir.mkdir();
            }
            FileWriter fWriter = new FileWriter(fileName);
            if(lastConnAddr != null)
                fWriter.write(lastConnAddr);
            fWriter.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    // Limpiar lista de dispositivos.
    private void clearBtDevData()
    {
        remoteDevices = new Vector<BluetoothDevice>();
    }
    // add paired device to list
    private void addPairedDevices()
    {
        BluetoothDevice pairedDevice;
        Iterator<BluetoothDevice> iter = (mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices()).iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext())
        {
            pairedDevice = iter.next();
            remoteDevices.add(pairedDevice);
            adapter.add(pairedDevice.getName() +"\n["+pairedDevice.getAddress()+"] [Paired]");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bluetooth_menu);
        // Setting
        btAddrBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextAddressBT);
        connectButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonConnectBT);
        searchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonSearchBT);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
        context = this;
        // Setting
        loadSettingFile();
        bluetoothSetup();



        // Connect, Disconnect -- Button
        connectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if(!bluetoothPort.isConnected()) // Connect routine.
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Conectar(btAddrBox.getText().toString());
                        //btConn(mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(btAddrBox.getText().toString()));
                    }
                    catch(IllegalArgumentException e)
                    {
                        // Bluetooth Address Format [OO:OO:OO:OO:OO:OO]
                        Log.e(TAG,e.getMessage(),e);
                        //AlertView.showAlert(e.getMessage(), context);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return;
                    }
                }
                else // Disconnect routine.
                {
                    // Always run.
                    btDisconn();
                }
            }
        });
        // Search Button
        searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering())
                {
                    clearBtDevData();
                    adapter.clear();
                    mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
                }
                else
                {
                    mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                }
            }
        });
        // Bluetooth Device List
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        addPairedDevices();
        // Connect - click the List item.
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
            {
                BluetoothDevice btDev = remoteDevices.elementAt(arg2);
                String Mac = String.valueOf(remoteDevices.elementAt(arg2));
                if(mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering())
                {
                    mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                }
                btAddrBox.setText(btDev.getAddress());
                //btConn(btDev);
                Conectar(Mac);
            }
        });

        // UI - Event Handler.
        // Search device, then add List.
        discoveryResult = new BroadcastReceiver()
        {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
                    String key;
                BluetoothDevice remoteDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                if(remoteDevice != null)
                {
                    if(remoteDevice.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED)
                    {
                        key = remoteDevice.getName() +"\n["+remoteDevice.getAddress()+"]";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        key = remoteDevice.getName() +"\n["+remoteDevice.getAddress()+"] [Paired]";
                    }
                    remoteDevices.add(remoteDevice);
                    adapter.add(key);
                }
            }
        };
        registerReceiver(discoveryResult, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
        searchStart = new BroadcastReceiver()
        {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
                connectButton.setEnabled(false);
                btAddrBox.setEnabled(false);
                searchButton.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.bt_stop_search_btn));
            }
        };
        registerReceiver(searchStart, new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED));
        searchFinish = new BroadcastReceiver()
        {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
                connectButton.setEnabled(true);
                btAddrBox.setEnabled(true);
                searchButton.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.bt_search_btn));
            }
        };
        registerReceiver(searchFinish, new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED));

    }
    //Funcion Para Conectar solo Mac en String
    private void Conectar(final String MacAddres)
    {
        AsyncBluetooth task = new AsyncBluetooth();
        task.execute(MacAddres);
    }
    // Bluetooth Metodo Desconectar.
    public void btDisconn()
    {
        try
        {
            bluetoothPort.disconnect();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        if((hThread != null) && (hThread.isAlive()))
            hThread.interrupt();
        // UI
        connectButton.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.dev_conn_btn));
        list.setEnabled(true);
        btAddrBox.setEnabled(true);
        searchButton.setEnabled(true);
        Toast.makeText(context, getResources().getString(R.string.bt_disconn_msg), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }




    //ClaSE Nueva de Asyntask ConexionBluetooth

    public class AsyncBluetooth extends AsyncTask<String, Void,Integer>
    {
        private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(ConexionBluetooth.this);


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            dialog.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.bt_tab));
            dialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.connecting_msg));
            dialog.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
            Integer resultado = null;

            try
            {
                SharedPreferences bluetooth = getSharedPreferences("ConexionBluetooth",0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = bluetooth.edit();
                editor.putString("Mac",params[0]);
                editor.commit();
                lastConnAddr = params[0];
                bluetoothPort.connect(lastConnAddr);
                resultado = Integer.valueOf(0);
            }catch (IOException e)
            {
                resultado = Integer.valueOf(-1);
            }


            return resultado;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            if (result.intValue() == 0)
            {
                RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
                hThread = new Thread(rh);
                hThread.start();
                // UI
                connectButton.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.dev_disconn_btn));
                list.setEnabled(false);
                btAddrBox.setEnabled(false);
                searchButton.setEnabled(false);
                if(dialog.isShowing())
                    dialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(context, getResources().getString(R.string.bt_conn_msg), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else
            {

                if(dialog.isShowing())
                    dialog.dismiss();
                AlertView.showAlert(getResources().getString(R.string.bt_conn_fail_msg),
                        getResources().getString(R.string.dev_check_msg), context);
            }

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }

}
```

Y lo que estoy haciendo es que en mi pantalla de login ahí mandar de nuevo a llamar mi Asynctask para la conexión me truena

```
 SharedPreferences bluetooth = getSharedPreferences("ConexionBluetooth",0);
        AsyncBluetooth tas2 = new AsyncBluetooth();
        tas2.execute(bluetooth.getString("Mac",""));

public class AsyncBluetooth extends AsyncTask<String, Void,Integer>
    {
        private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            dialog.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.bt_tab));
            dialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.connecting_msg));
            dialog.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
            Integer resultado = null;

            try
            {
                lastConnAddr = params[0];
                bluetoothPort.connect(params[0]);
                resultado = Integer.valueOf(0);
            }catch (IOException e)
            {
                resultado = Integer.valueOf(-1);
            }


            return resultado;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            if (result.intValue() == 0)
            {
                RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
                hThread = new Thread(rh);
                hThread.start();
                // UI
                if(dialog.isShowing())
                    dialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(context, getResources().getString(R.string.bt_conn_msg), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else
            {

                if(dialog.isShowing())
                    dialog.dismiss();
                AlertView.showAlert(getResources().getString(R.string.bt_conn_fail_msg),
                        getResources().getString(R.string.dev_check_msg), context);
            }

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
```

Error, te comento que el llamdo de Asynctask lo realizo en Oncreate no se si este bien.

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
>                     Process: mx.com.oncontrol.oncontroldesconectado, PID: 5021
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>                         at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
>                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
>                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
>                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>                         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   com.citizen.port.android.BluetoothPort.connect(java.lang.String)' on a
>   null object reference
>                         at mx.com.oncontrol.oncontroldesconectado.Login$AsyncBluetooth.doInBackground(Login.java:506)
>                         at mx.com.oncontrol.oncontroldesconectado.Login$AsyncBluetooth.doInBackground(Login.java:485)
>                         at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
>                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
>                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
>                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
>                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)

funcion bluetooth port que utilizo para conectarme a la impresora

```
 public void connect(String address) throws IOException {
        BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
        if(mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }

        if(!this.isValidAddress(address)) {
            throw new IOException("Bluetooth Address is not valid.");
        } else {
            this.setBTSocket(bluetoothDevice);
            this.connectCommon();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Que error te da?

Comment: Y agregue el error

Comment: Has comprobado que el array de params no sea null cuando entra ahi. Parece que la excepcion que te da es porque algo es null al pasar por doInBackground

Comment: si ,trae datos, pero al momento de que para esta linea bluetoothPort.connect(lastConnAddr); es cuando truena, puse la imagen de cuando esta en el motodo IBackground

Comment: y bluetoothPort es distinto de null?

Comment: bluetoothport es una funciona de la libreria de la impresora marca citizen, te agregue la funcion que utlizo de la clase bluetoothport

Answer (score 1):

Veo que al iniciar tu aplicación (`onCreateView()`), llamas el método `bluetoothSetup()`, que es el que habilita Bluetooth.

Modifica tu método en la parte donde encuentra que no esta habilitado el Adaptador.

```
  public void bluetoothSetup()
    {
        // Initialize
        clearBtDevData();
        bluetoothPort = BluetoothPort.getInstance();
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null)
        {
            // Device does not support Bluetooth
            return;
        }
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
        {
             //Habilita Bluetooth!
             mBluetoothAdapter.enable(); 

            //Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            //startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }
    }
```

No necesitas realizar el `Intent`, de hecho usando `startActivityForResult()` no tienes un método `onActivityResult` para realizar alguna acción.

---

#### Habilitar `Bluetooth` :

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();    
if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {//No esta activo?
    mBluetoothAdapter.enable(); //Habilita Bluetooth.
}else{
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth esta actualmente activo!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

#### Deshabilitar `Bluetooth` :

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();    
if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) { //Esta activo?
    mBluetoothAdapter.disable(); //deshabilita Bluetooth.
}
```